# So I get this error when I am trying to debug

Tags: debugging

jGRASP exec: java -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,server=y Date

could someone please shed some light on what this is trying to tell me

Answer (score 0):

That's the normal startup for the target process. You could do the same at the command line if you wanted to start the process first, then connect a debugger. Java should respond with the connection port number, which will quickly be overwritten with the message "----jGRASP: connected to debugger.". If that isn't happening and there is no other error message, and if you are on Windows, use "Settings" > "Java Debug Settings" to change the preferred connector to "Shared Memory" and see if that fixes it.